# Can't use any bundle command in TextMate

Tags: textmate

Just did a fresh install. I can't seem to run any bundle command. Always get an error like:

```
Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/lib/escape.rb:23:in `e_url': private method `gsub' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

*Running Textmate 2, latest build on Lion 10.7.4*

Comment: Have you checked that it affects all commands and not for example ones written in Ruby? What is the PATH variable set to?

Comment: I set PATH to the result of 'echo $PATH' in Terminal. btw should the variable name PATH or TM_PATH?

Comment: I don't have TextMate 2, but at least in my installation of 1.5.11 TM_PATH is unset and only PATH is listed in the shell variables tab. There's no search results for TM_PATH on the mailing list.